# what can one call the jsp file 2 controller files in java?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller, multiprocessing

what can one call the jsp file 2 controller files in java??

This is Jsp File

```
<form:form commandName="userProfile" method="post" action="createuserform.html" id="userForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">       
<table class="detail">
<tr>
    <th><label for="userProfile.userName"><fmt:message key="global.username"/>:</label></th>
    <td>
        <form:input path="userProfile.userName" id="userName" size="50" maxlength="300"/>
        <form:errors path="userProfile.userName" cssClass="fieldError"/>
    </td>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <td>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value=" Save " onclick="return checkPassword();"/>
        <input type="button" class="button" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='<c:out value="${ctx}"/>/listuser.html'">
    </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

and this 2 examples file Controller in java
This is CreateUserFormController.java

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class CreateUserFormController extends SimpleFormController {


    public CreateUserFormController() {
        setCommandName("userProfile");               
        setCommandClass(UserUploadModelHelper.class);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ... 
}
```

This is file CreateUserLogFromController.java

```
public class CreateUserLogFromController extends SimpleFormController {


    public CreateUserLogFromController(){
        setCommandName("userLog");
        setCommandClass(UserUploadModelHelper.class);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

how to call jsp files two the controller file???

Comment: You don't "call" controllers. You make http requests which your server passed/maps to controllers so they can be processed.

Comment: any examples?? how can i doing...

Comment: i see u r learning spring. use this link [http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/] to try your first hello world program